# libgdal26 looks broken on the ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, 22.04, django

I've upgraded my system to Ubuntu 22.04 and found problems using the `libgdal26` package

The `libgdal26` package is used to have my Django v.2.2 application working. It works fine on Ubuntu 20.04.

After the upgrade, I found the following problem:

- `libgdal26` depends on `libproj15` and `libgeotiff5`
- `libgeotiff5` depends on `libproj22`

As a result, loading `libgdal26` the application loads both, `libproj15` and `libproj22`, libraries, which leads to core dumped or/and unexpected exceptions, etc.

```
seva@SEVA-MOBILE:~/swat/sharing$ ldd /usr/lib/libgdal.so.26 | grep libproj
        libproj.so.15 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.15 (0x00007f5941800000)
        libproj.so.22 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.22 (0x00007f593dc00000)
```

For example, this is a part of the (python executable) backtrace after the core was dumped:

```
#9  0x00007f5caa4a7cb3 in osgeo::proj::common::UnitOfMeasure::~UnitOfMeasure() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.22
#10 0x00007f5cb2a45495 in __run_exit_handlers (status=0, listp=0x7f5cb2c19838 <__exit_funcs>, run_list_atexit=run_list_atexit@entry=true, run_dtors=run_dtors@entry=true)
    at ./stdlib/exit.c:113
#11 0x00007f5cb2a45610 in __GI_exit (status=<optimized out>) at ./stdlib/exit.c:143
#12 0x00007f5cb2a29d97 in __libc_start_call_main (main=main@entry=0x5feeb0, argc=argc@entry=3, argv=argv@entry=0x7fffc691e1f8) at ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:74
#13 0x00007f5cb2a29e40 in __libc_start_main_impl (main=0x5feeb0, argc=3, argv=0x7fffc691e1f8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, 
    stack_end=0x7fffc691e1e8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:392
#14 0x00000000005fede5 in _start ()
(gdb)
```

The `libproj` is not the only duplicated library loaded with the `libgdal`. They are also:

```
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007ff5d8000000)
        libcrypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 (0x00007ff5d6000000)
```

```
        libdap.so.25 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdap.so.25 (0x00007ff5d9662000)
        libdap.so.27 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdap.so.27 (0x00007ff5d647a000)
```

```
        libwebp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.6 (0x00007ff5daf96000)
        libwebp.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.7 (0x00007ff5d7a39000)
```

Comment: Have you looked into if that app Django v.2.2 works with Ubuntu 22.04 or do you need a newer version?

Comment: I am developing a part of the application based on Django 2.2 and used to have virtualenv development environment on my host. Yes, I definitely can use any other available option, but my point is that the libgdal26 package is broken in the Ubuntu 22.04 now. I should probably create a ticket somewhere for the package providers to fix it, but don't know where.

Comment: I've found a base point. The libgdal26 is absent in the Ubuntu 22.04 and can not be used at all because of it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a base point. The `libgdal26` package is absent in Ubuntu 22.04 and can not be used at all because of it. As a result, using Django 2.2 with the GIS subsystem without problems is unavailable on the system.

Note: GIS subsystem of the Django 2.2 doesn't know about the last changes in the `libgdal` library and swaps coordinates because of this.

Comment: You may want to file a report with whom ever maintains that app.